# Google Analytics Do Similar Goal Funnels cause problems?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, analytics, goal-tracking

So I've been asked to create goal funnels within google analytics which are identical except for the first url in the funnel. For example:

Step 1: Sales page #1
/
Step 2: Info page
/
Step 3: Checkout page
/
Destination goal: Thank you page

And the second funnel would be the same except Sales page #1 would be Sales page #2.

My question is because the destination goal is the same, if one funnel is generating more goal completions than the other, would it backfill up on the less successful funnel and cause the numbers to be identical?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't cause a problem at all. I think you're applying human thinking to a computer problem.

If the pages are different then analytics will treat them as separate chains of links. No issue whatsoever.

Of course the actual issue is with someone looking at the different reports / goals in 6 months remember the differences, and report correctly back to the business. Now, that's a human problem.

You should also test as well to prove they're different.

Comment: This is where its confusing, because if a user completes the goal, and there are 2 goals with the same destination wouldn't it count for both goals?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Try using Google tag manager to set up UTMs which would result in separate links for the goals.

Comment: Well I don't think I can use UTM because the links on ad campaigns and affiliates already have traffic being generated and using UTM codes. I read about funnels being backfilled on this [KissMetrics article](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/conversion-funnel-survival-guide/)